# Search for and select different field from long JSON obj

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON obj like below - which has a huge list of offerValue objs.

```
{
    "Code": 0,
    "response": "SUCCESS",
    "offerValue": [
        {
            "id": "111",
            "name": "ABC",
            "flag": "V" 
        },
        {
            "id": "222",
            "name": "DEF",
            "flag": "A"
        },
        {
            "id": "333",
            "name": "XYZ",
            "flag": "G"
        },
        {
            "id": "444",
            "name": "FER",
            "flag": "H"
        }
    ],
    "sessionId": null
}
```

Using ES6, I want to search for name=ABC and if it exists, pick the respective flag value from that obj ("V" in the example case)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Chris for the reference...

The answer to the questions is -

```
let jsonobj = {
    "Code": 0,
    "response": "SUCCESS",
    "offerValue": [
        {
            "id": "111",
            "name": "ABC",
            "flag": "V" 
        },
        {
            "id": "222",
            "name": "DEF",
            "flag": "A"
        },
        {
            "id": "333",
            "name": "XYZ",
            "flag": "G"
        },
        {
            "id": "444",
            "name": "FER",
            "flag": "H"
        }
    ],
    "sessionId": null
}

let offers = jsonobj.offerValue;

let result = offers.find(({name}) => name === 'ABC'));

if (result){
console.log(result.flag)
//other logic

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply reduce the array to a single flag. Ex:

```
const flag = obj.offerValue.reduce((acc, offer) => {
if (offer.name === 'ABC') return offer.flag;
return acc;
}, null);
```